# Load data from big query into spark dataframe using AWS Glue (Failed to find data source: bigquery)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, aws-glue

I am trying to load data from big query into a spark dataframe using AWS Glue.

I am using spark 3.1 and have downloaded the [big-query-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector?tab=readme-ov-file) "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-3.1-bigquery:0.36.1" and put it in a S3 bucket.

Inside the glue notebook i am again creating a spark session and loading data into df using:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Data from BQ") \
    .config("spark.jars", "s3://path/to/driver.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .load("project.dataset.table")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o127.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigquery.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351).
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigquery.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spark.jars.package`

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Data from BQ") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.36.1") \
    .getOrCreate()
```